# Django - Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field

Tags: python, django

When i click on my product this error appears. I already migrate the shop models and admin, and on the /admin i rename the products, slugs and descriptions. 
The error that i get when i try to go to the product page is this:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: available, category, category_id, created, id, image, order_items, price, translations, updated
```

I dont know what to do my migrations worked fine, and the server is running okay, until i click a product.

shop/models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields


class Category(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                db_index=True),
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                                db_index=True,
                                unique=True)
    )

    class Meta:
        # ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category',
                       args=[self.slug])


class Product(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True),
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True),
        description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                              blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # class Meta:
    #    ordering = ('name',)
    #    index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from parler.admin import TranslatableAdmin
from .models import Category, Product


@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']

    def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return {'slug': ('name',)}


@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug', 'price',
                    'available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_editable = ['price', 'available']

    def get_prepopulated_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return {'slug': ('name',)}
```

shop/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with TranslatedFields, but in shop/models.py you are attempting to call `self.slug`, which appears to be a subset of the `translations` field.

So try:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.translations.slug])
```

Comment: doesn't work, when y type `self.translations.slug` slug is not an option, if i try to put name that is in translations its okay, i tried calling only self.translations but doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Django [Slug Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/).

You will find your answer.

Comment: mm didn't find a lot about slug, and what i found was not useful, still in problems, i tried the answer below, but didn't work